# ToCharArray equivalent for List<string>

Tags: c#, arrays, addrange

How do you split a string to a List? I'm looking for the equivalent of ToCharArray but instead to make it a List.

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<string> datalist = new List<string>();
datalist.AddRange(new List<string>{"A","B","C"});
```

How do you convert data so it will be accepted by AddRange?

Comment: So a string to a list of single character strings? `str.Select(c => c.ToString()).ToList()`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you want a list of characters, then you would use a `List<char>` rather than `List<string>`, and then you don't have to do anything at all to the string. The `AddRange` method takes an `IEnumerable<char>` and the `String` class happens to implement `IEnumerable<char>`:

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<char> datalist = new List<char>();
datalist.AddRange(data);
```

If you want a `List<string>` to hold the characters anyway, then you would need to convert each character to a string:

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<string> datalist = new List<string>();
datalist.AddRange(data.Select(c => c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 5):

Since the initialization of a new list instance accepts a collection whose elements will be copied to the new list, the answer of Guffa can be shortened to:

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<char> datalist = new List<char>(data);
```

And:

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<string> datalist = new List<string>(data.Select(c => c.ToString()));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the result as a `List<char>`, `str.ToList()` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way

```
string data = "ABCDEFGHIJ1fFJKAL";
List<string> datalist = new List<string>();
datalist.AddRange(data.Select (d => d.ToString()));
```